# How to install all the Compiz plugins (excepting those which are unsupported or experimental) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, software-installation, plugins

I just bought a HP laptop yesterday and I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.
I want some awesome Compiz plugins (like cube rotation,cube deformation,fire painting,water,etc.),but I don't know how to install them and I don't remember how I installed them on my desktop,which runs Ubuntu 12.04,so please tell me what to do (as clear as possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install them as:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-main-default
```